# ExtJS localstorage proxy model/store issue

Tags: extjs, model, local-storage, store

I'm using ExtJS 5.1.0 and running into a strange problem.

I have the following model:

```
Ext.define('cardioCatalogQT.model.Load', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config:{
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            {name: 'key', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'comparator', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'value', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'type', type: 'string'}
        ]

    }
});
```

And the Store:

```
Ext.define('cardioCatalogQT.store.Payload', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.Payload',
    // add package.framework=ext to .sencha/app/sencha.cfg
    config:{

        model: 'cardioCatalogQT.model.Load',
        storeId: 'Payload',
        autoLoad: true,

        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage'
        }
    }
});
```

When I add a record to the store:

```
var payload = Ext.create('cardioCatalogQT.store.Payload');

payload.add({
    type: 'dx',
    key: item.data.code,
    comparator: 'eq',
    value: item.data.description
});

payload.sync();
```

The data in localstorage look like all the records except for #7 and #11 in the attached image

[image]

However, when I add the field elements to the store like this:

```
Ext.define('cardioCatalogQT.store.Payload', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.Payload',
    // add package.framework=ext to .sencha/app/sencha.cfg
    config:{
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            {name: 'type', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'key', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'comparator', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
        ] ,

        //model: 'cardioCatalogQT.model.Load',
        storeId: 'Payload',
        autoLoad: true,

        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage'
        }
    }
});
```

I get the desired results in 7 and 11.

One other issue, is instead of giving an actual name to the model record, I get the very not useful name of ext-data-proxy-localstorage-N for the model instance.

Also, I am getting this error when referencing the model via the store:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (cardioCatalogQT.model.Load, line 0)

I have done a sencha app build and no errors were thrown.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong (I am basically doing what I've done with Sencha Touch, where I had much success)? Is this a bug, perhaps?

Comment: For the 404 error : shouldn't the model declaration in the store be just short `model : Load` ?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't try this. I had assumed (possibly erroneously) that I had to provide the full namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was for ExtJS, to get the desired name on the store, you have to specify and id in the proxy:

```
 proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id  : 'payload'
        }
```

Now, the model instances in my localstorage are showing up as desired, and I can query them using standard methods, like findRecord. Good times!

Moral of the story: ExtJS has different behaviors than Touch

Comment: Helps to read the API documentation and NOT assume the behaviors are going to be the same (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage): "Our Search model contains just two fields - id and query - plus a Proxy definition. The only configuration we need to pass to the LocalStorage proxy is an id. This is important as it separates the Model data in this Proxy from all others. The localStorage API puts all data into a single shared namespace, so by setting an id we enable LocalStorageProxy to manage the saved Search data."

Comment: How did you specify id property? I am using sencha architect and it won't let me do this

Comment: I do everything manually in an IDE (WebStorm) using a vim plug-in. I have never had problems creating the models and stores manually. In fact, I would strongly recommend you try this, since you obviously have more control over the process (never trust a GUI-device thingie to do it for you).